# Filtering in dataTable after editing the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I having a jquery Data table, where I can do edit and save the data to database, but the problem is in search/filtering, eg., I am having a values in a dataTable **OldAAA,OldBBB,OldCCC** and when I do search, filtering is happening properly and data is displaying properly in the dataTable. Problem is when I am editing and saving any one  value(**eg. OldAAA I changed to NewAAA**) then **NewAAA** will get updated in database and **NewAAA** will display in the dataTable (through ajax), and while searching for new values(**NewAAA**) its show "**No matching records found**", and If I am searching with old value(**OldAAA**) which I have updated to **newAAA**, then in the dataTable I am seeing updated value (**NewBBB**).( filtering is happening with out any problem If I do the refresh and search, but req not to refresh) Please I am want help, how to search new value.

```
var userDataTable=null;
function callDataTableOptions(){
    userDataTable= $("#userDataTable").DataTable({
                 "bSort": false, 
                "iDisplayLength": 10 ,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bPaginate": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                     "sDom": '<"top"fip>',
                     "bStateSave": false,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ messages",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 messages",
                        "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
                        "sSearch": "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sPrevious": "<",
                            "sNext": ">",
                            "sFirst":"",
                            "sLast":""
                        },
                        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                        tableTools: {
                            "sRowSelect": "single"
                        }
                    }
            }); 
    }
```

Thank you,
[image: Data table sample]

Comment: kindly include your `searching for new values` javascript code

Comment: Searching script is ah ajax script?its load on each time of search?  or get the data only on windows loading?

Comment: Please post your code how u are adding data to Datatable after ajax call and how you are initializing the Datatable

Comment: @prasad, Thanks for replying, I am not writing any code for searching, just using the jquery dataTable search api. And I am searching only after the ajax response and also I have checked that new values are getting appended to DOM after the ajax response and I don't know from there the jquery dataTable search will fetch the values..,

Comment: @VenkataKrishnaReddy, I am getting the object from ajax response and I am iterating the data from the Object and appending into the table.  function createDynamicTable(data){for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var user=data[i].setUser;"<tr>"+
   "<td cstyle='width:15%'>"+ "<div>"+user+"</div>"+"<td>"+"</tr>"

Comment: @Khusboo connect with your dataTable to database via ajax script.Run this ajax script each time of search the input.Its will overwrite the exist data all the time.so you can easily get the updated values

Comment: @Prasad, could you please help me how to connect the dataTable to database through ajax

Comment: @Khusboo post yout dataTable And searching input javascript

Comment: @prasad, added please check